# Multiple android app projects sharing code in Clean-Architecture

Tags: android, clean-architecture, android-architecture

I want to create three related android apps (employee, Manager, Secretary) in clean-architecture and also share common classes (utils, Ui & etc.) among all three apps in order to reduce code duplication. Each project has multi-modular clean-architecture design. Would you guide me on how to connect these three projects to the shared classes, please? Is there any sample code for my case?

[image]

My project after using clean-architecture book by Alexandru Dumbravan:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might do some separation code between apps. You can merge it in you `settings.gradle` to merge all apps/libraries in one project.

[Here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP5Hv.png)

There is 4 additional code/library in 1 project which is app, xxxapi,xxxauth and xxxcommon.

So you can set your `settings.gradle` into something like :

```
include ':app', ':xxxapi', ':xxxauth', ':xxxcommon'
```

If you already set that code, you can use it in all your code in one project as well.